# reactjs json with layered data

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to understand how to call json data using React and the map technique. I am specifically having trouble with acquiring layered data. In my example json code below, this would be the content under `side`.

As is, my first return statement works. That is, I am able to retrieve a list with the contents of `dish`. However, my second return statement returns an error wherein the map cannot define the content of my call, or `side`.

The end goal of this is that I would like to have a list that outputs the nested data that coincides with the main.

```
getInitialState:function(){
  return {fulldata: {main:[{side:[]}]}}
},

componentDidMount:function(){
  var self = this;
  $.getJSON('https://yooarel.com', function(resultes){
  self.setState({fulldata: resultes});
  }); 
},

render:function(){
  var self = this;
  return (<div>
    <ul>
    {this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(break, i){
    return <li key={i}>{break.dish}</li>})}
      <ul>
      {this.state.fulldata.main.side.map(function(make, o){
        return <li key={o}>{make.platter}</li>)}}
      </ul>
    </ul>
</div>);
}
```

Meanwhile my hypothetical `yooarel` JSON file would look like so:

```
{
  "main": [
    { "dish": "steak",
      "side": [
       {"platter": "yogurt"},
       {"platter": "popcorn"}
      ]
    },
    { "dish": "fish",
      "side": [
      {"platter": "salad"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because main is an array and you are treating it as object.
Try this instead.

```
{
   this.state.fulldata.main.map(function(m,i){
     return m.side.map(function(make, o){
       return <li key={o}>{make.platter}</li>)}
     }
   })
 }
```